# Fact check: Was remdesivir treatment associated with a 62% reduction in mortality rate?

Tags: covid-19, antivirals

On July 10, 2020, [Gilead announced](https://www.gilead.com/news-and-press/press-room/press-releases/2020/7/gilead-presents-additional-data-on-investigational-antiviral-remdesivir-for-the-treatment-of-covid-19)

> remdesivir treatment was associated with significantly improved clinical
> recovery and a 62 percent reduction in the risk of mortality compared to
> standard of care.... The mortality rate for patients treated with remdesivir in
> the analysis was 7.6 percent at Day 14 compared with 12.5 percent among patients
> not taking remdesivir (adjusted odds ratio 0.38, 95% confidence interval
> 0.22-0.68, p=0.001).

How is the 62% reduction calculated? Naively, a drop from 12.5% to 7.6% appears to be a 39% (=(12.5-7.6)/12.5) reduction.

Comment: 12.5 x .62 = 7.75

Comment: @CareyGregory: But would that mean if there was a slight drop in mortality from 12% to 11%, Gilead would claim a 92% drop in mortality!?

Comment: Heh, good point.

Comment: And this is why, as a statistician, I wish we could all spend some time learning odds ratios and use those. It's not easy and they aren't intuitive, but once you get it you get it, and both positive and negative effects make sense. Percent changes are incredibly easy to misinterpret or misstate.

Comment: This is really interesting. I can't answer the question, but would highly appreciate if anyone else could. @BryanKrause, can you answer it, as a statistician?

Comment: @Don_S It's better to just read the study numbers, which are not under dispute. "The mortality rate for patients treated with remdesivir in the analysis was 7.6 percent at Day 14 compared with 12.5 percent among patients not taking remdesivir (adjusted odds ratio 0.38, 95% confidence interval 0.22-0.68, p=0.001)" Stop there, ignore the rest.

Comment: @Don_S https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/324410/converting-odds-ratio-to-percentage-increase-reduction might be useful, too.

Comment: (also, I don't think they got the number the way @CareyGregory suggested, that doesn't come out quite right. They probably used "1 - OR" where OR is 0.38. It's also an "adjusted" OR so it is marginalized on other variables in the model. Either way, this is a nonsense number and should never have been reported the way it was.)

Comment: @BryanKrause: Do you think it likely that what Gilead meant to say is that the adjusted *risk ratio* was found to be 0.38 (= 1 - 0.62)? and by "adjusted" they mean [age-adjusted Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel risk ratio](https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704-ep713_confounding-em/BS704-EP713_Confounding-EM7.html)?

Comment: @unutbu I think it's more likely they just screwed up, and had a non-statistician write the press release. They wouldn't be the first and won't be the last. I don't take a lot of value out of press release statistics, they can publish a peer reviewed paper if they want scientists to take their results seriously.

Comment: [The Solidarity trial asserts](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2020/10/remdesivir-and-interferon-fall-flat-who-s-megastudy-covid-19-treatments) that remdesivir does not lower mortality nor delay the moment patients need ventilation.